# Pass JSON object from php to php

Tags: php, json, post

I have a php file (sample1.php) which calls another php file (sample2.php) 
through header function.

```
      header("Location: "sample2.php");
```

How can I pass a JSON object from one php to another.
I need to POST the JSON object, so that the second file can access it using

```
      if( isset($_POST["json"]) ) { ... }
```

Comment: put it in the session and in next page get it using $_SESSION

Comment: Or remove `header` from first file and  in second file use `include('first page')`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [cURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) method

```
<?php  
//set POST variables
$url = 'sample2.php';
$fields = array(
    'json' => urlencode($json/*your json that want to pass*/),
);

//url-ify the data for the POST
foreach($fields as $key=>$value) { $fields_string .= $key.'='.$value.'&'; }
rtrim($fields_string, '&');

//open connection
$ch = curl_init();

//set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, count($fields));
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);

//execute post
$result = curl_exec($ch);

//close connection
curl_close($ch);

?>
```

Or you can refer this [link](https://davidwalsh.name/curl-post) :)

Answer (score 0):

If you absolutely have to use header() to proceed to sample2.php then you can't use $_POST to get the data when in sample2.php.

Put it in session storage (in sample1.php):

```
$_SESSION['jsonData'] = $yourJsonData;
```

Then after arriving in sample2.php:

```
if( isset($_SESSION["jsonData"]) ) { ... }
```

Don't forget to initialize your sessions, etc. Refer to http://php.net/manual/en/session.examples.basic.php

Comment: I found out the solution, call a javascript function from sample1.php.This JS function posts a JSON object to sample2.php.